# Undefined id fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

My backbonejs app has a model that looks like:

```
var Store = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot: "/stores/" + this.id
});
```

and I have a router that looks like:

```
var StoreRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
   routes: {
      'stores/edit/:id': 'edit'
   },
   edit: function(id){
      var editStoresView = new EditStoresView({
         el: ".wrapper",
         model: new Store({ id: id })
      });
   }
});
var storeRouter = new StoreRouter();
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, hashChange: false });
```

but then in my view I have:

```
var EditStoresView = Backbone.View.extend({
   ...
   render: function() {
       this.model.fetch();
       this.$el.append ( JST['tmpl/' + "edit"]( this.model.toJSON() ) );
   }
```

Unfortunately, this gives a call to localhost/stores/undefined, but I'm not sure why?

Comment: In the first Backbone Model code part, it seems that a quote is missing...? `urlRoot: "return "/stores/" + this.id`

Comment: @SiZiOUS, thanks I messed up posting the question, but that's not how my real code looks like. I updated with fix.

Comment: I guessed it was a copy-paste error. Sorry I think I can't help more since I don't know Blackbone.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you're getting "localhost/stores/undefined" call is because you have below code.

```
urlRoot: "/stores/" + this.id
```

When you use model.fetch() it uses urlRoot plus ID of the model to fetch the data. In other words, you should have urlRoot as something like "/stores/" only and should not directly apply any ID.

One more thing, you should write below code in "sucess" callback of the fetch() method because the model data won't be available as soon as you call fetch() (since it's a sync request to the server).

```
this.model.fetch();    
this.$el.append ( JST['tmpl/' + "edit"]( this.model.toJSON() ) );
```

Change that to

```
   var el = this.$el;
   this.model.fetch({ success : function(model, response, options) {
       el.append ( JST['tmpl/' + "edit"]( model.toJSON() ) );
   });
```

Hope that helps! Happy coding!

Comment: Sai is right, but another reason you're getting `undefined` is that you're trying to get `this.id` before the model has been instantiated. There is no value for that yet. If you did need a different `urlRoot` with the id, you could do something like: `urlRoot: function() { return '/stores/' + this.id + '/extra' }`

Comment: @Sai Dubbaka, Thanks for the answer, but now the js is requesting just /stores/ without an id?